# DART post with multipart/form-data

Tags: dart, multipartform-data, dart-html, dart-io

in DART lang, how to specify POST request Content-Type to be

```
multipart/form-data
```

My DART code is:

```dart
sendDatas(dynamic data) {
final req = new HttpRequest();
req.onReadyStateChange.listen((Event e) {
  if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
      (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
    window.alert("upload complete");
  }
});
req.open("POST", "/upload");
req.send(data);
```

}

I am doing POST with a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `HttpRequest.postFormData(url, data)` here. Then you can use the following:

```dart
FormData data = new FormData(); // from dart:html

data.append(key, value);

HttpRequest.request('/upload', method: 'POST', sendData: data).then((HttpRequest r) {
  // ...
});
```

Regards, Robert

Comment: any idea why I get this when making console `err` in Terminal: `no multipart boundary param in Content-Type` /// I'm still using my code

Comment: Can you show the complete code. My code should work.

Comment: when adding your code, I get something like this: `The argument type 'FormData (/Users/MyUserName/Downloads/dart/dart-sdk/lib/html/dartium/
 html_dartium.dart)' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'Map (/Users/MyUserName/Downloads/
 dart/dart-sdk/lib/core/map.dart)'`

Comment: I changed my code. It was the wrong function that I used.

Comment: Concerning your error: I guess multipart/form-data requires the boundary value set: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 - e.g.  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x'. It is much better to use FormData as it does those things for you!

Comment: in your code, what are you using the `key` and `value` for?

Comment: It's the data for your form you want to submit. When you have a text input like `<input type="text" name="name" value="Robert">` then key is "name" and value is "Robert".

Comment: i'm having an `input type="file"`, doing it like you said, but still getting server err: `http: no such file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60957/discussion-between-bboy-and-robert).

Answer (score 0):

On the server it is supported by the [`http` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http). This package can also be used in the browser but it seems the `multipart_request.dart` file can't be imported in the browser because it uses `dart:io`;

I suggest creating a feature request on http://dartbug.com/new.

You could also try to copy the code from the [http] package and remove the references to the `io` package and use browser API instead.

How it could be used on the server is shown here http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.1+1/index.html#http/http.MultipartRequest